# PIVOT without table?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm currently working with a set of values passed into my query by SSRS. In this case, it's an indeterminate number of year. For instance, the values may be '2014', '2015', and '2016' or it may just be '2016' any any such variation.

I'd like to do something like a PIVOT where I can create a table with all of the years in a single column so that I can cross join with another table of each month to get a year/month listing.

Any idea how I'd go about starting on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still looking on how to handle this situation, but I ended up turning my script into a stored procedure and then passing in the parameter as an argument to the stored procedure. This caused the parameter to be passed as a single string and then I could split it like Nolan Shang had suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a function of split string.
For example:

**1.String**

```
DECLARE @para VARCHAR(max)
SET @para='''2015'',''2016'',''2017'''
SELECT n.yr FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(XML,'<n>'+REPLACE(@para,',','</n><n>')+'</n>'))) x(doc)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT s.b.value('.','varchar(10)') AS yr FROM x.doc.nodes('n')s(b)) n
```

```
yr
-----------
'2015'
'2016'
'2017'
```

I am not sure that data type of you parameters.
If the variable is come to with columns of a table，you can use cross apply.
If they are multiple variables, you can just use select from values

**2.Variables**

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(10)='2015', @var2 VARCHAR(10)='2016', @var3 VARCHAR(10)='2017'
SELECT * FROM (VALUES(@var1),(@var2),(@var3)) t(yr)
```

**3. Column**

```
WITH paras(var1,var2,var3,var4)AS(
   SELECT '2015','2016','2016',null
)
SELECT t.yr FROM paras
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(var1),(var2),(var3),(var4))t(yr)
WHERE t.yr IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Unfortunately, (might be a difference in SSRS version) the variable isn't coming though in a manner I can do that.

According to SQL Server Profiler, the data is more like: '2014', '2015', '2016', and not as a single string.